# SQL Query to get country_name and count of occurances when another column is like

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQL tables , one called `trials` and has columns

```
 nct_id, 
 off_title, 
 brief_title
```

and the other one that is called `countries` and has columns

```
 nct_id 
 country_name
```

I want to write an sql query that finds :

the countries and number of occurancies (with count) when off_title or brief_title is like a specific input.

I have tried this query but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT country_name , count(country_name) as cnt

FROM trials,countries

WHERE off_title LIKE "%something%" or brief_title LIKE "%something%" 

GROUP BY country_name

ORDER BY cnt ASC
```

Comment: How are these tables related together? Via same `nct_id` ?

Comment: Yes. That is the way they are connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT country_name, count(*)
FROM countries c JOIN trials t on c.nct_id = t.nct_id
WHERE off_title LIKE "%something%" or brief_title LIKE "%something%"
GROUP BY country_name
```

Try to join tables together first.